# double clicking desktop file in Files does not launch application

Tags: system, files

If I double-click on any desktop file in /usr/share/applications, it open the file in Code rather than launching the application the way it used to before I upgraded to Horus. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: To clarify, these are `.desktop` definition files that are opening in VS Code rather than launching the application? 

Comment: Yes. gtk-launch still works however.